# matplotlib colorbar minor ticks color and number of minor ticks

Tags: python, matplotlib, colorbar

I have a matplotlib (v2.1.1) plot that includes a colorbar. When plotted on a figure with a white background, I get a colorbar as shown in one of the attached images. That is fine (though I'd love to know how to set the number of minor ticks).

[image]

However when I set the background to black using `fig.patch.set_facecolor(back_color)` with `back_color = 'black'` I get a color bar which lacks the minor ticks and the multiplier at the top. I've already changed the color of the y tick labels manually, but can't find out how to change the minor tick or multiplier colors.

[image]

[Edit] OK, here is a code which illustrates the problem. I solved the minor tick color problem, that leaves me with (in order of priority) the multiplier color & the number of minor ticks. The code is below, change the background variable to 1 from 0 to see the multiplier.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

background = 0
if background == 0:
  back_color='black'
  fore_color='white'
else:
  back_color='white'
  fore_color='black'
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
fig.patch.set_facecolor(back_color)
im = ax.imshow([[1e5,2e5],[0.1e5,1e5]])
ax.axis( 'off' )  # don't show the axes ticks/lines/etc. associated with the image
cb = plt.colorbar(im)
cb.formatter.set_scientific(True)
cb.formatter.set_powerlimits((0,0))
cbytick_obj = plt.getp(cb.ax, 'yticklabels' ) #Set y tick label color
plt.setp(cbytick_obj, color=fore_color)
cb.ax.tick_params(which = 'minor', length = 2, color = fore_color )
cb.ax.tick_params(which = 'major', length = 4, color = fore_color )
cb.ax.minorticks_on()
cb.update_ticks()
plt.show()
```

Comment: A useful start is usually a minimal code, I for example don't get the minor ticks...

Comment: Just realized there is a 400 char limit on a comment. Minimal example code  is below

Comment: Ouch! I mean I've edited the question to include code....

Comment: Please ask one question per question. For the number of minor ticks use e.g. `cb.ax.yaxis.set_minor_locator(matplotlib.ticker.AutoMinorLocator(10))`, but you could have found that out pretty easily by searching - no need to clutter a question with several problems at once.

Comment: Point taken on the # of questions. I had in fact found the AutoMinorLocator, but had placed it before the cb.ax.minorticks_on() line in my code. It seems that the minorticks_on() function resets the number of ticks to auto. Getting rid of that line & using AutoMinorLocator only works. Thanks for steering me back on the right path.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may use `rcParams` to set the required colors.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

background = 0
if background == 0:
  back_color='black'
  fore_color='white'
else:
  back_color='white'
  fore_color='black'

plt.rcParams["text.color"] = fore_color
plt.rcParams["axes.labelcolor"] = fore_color
plt.rcParams["xtick.color"] =  fore_color
plt.rcParams["ytick.color"] = fore_color

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
fig.patch.set_facecolor(back_color)
im = ax.imshow([[1e5,2e5],[0.1e5,1e5]])
ax.axis( 'off' )  # don't show the axes ticks/lines/etc. associated with the image
cb = plt.colorbar(im)
cb.formatter.set_scientific(True)
cb.formatter.set_powerlimits((0,0))

cb.ax.minorticks_on()
cb.update_ticks()
plt.show()
```

[image]

Also note that matplotlib has a `dark_background` style which seems to pretty much do what you are trying to accomplish manually.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

background = 0
if background == 0:
    plt.style.use("dark_background")

fig, ax = plt.subplots()

im = ax.imshow([[1e5,2e5],[0.1e5,1e5]])
ax.axis( 'off' )
cb = plt.colorbar(im)
cb.formatter.set_scientific(True)
cb.formatter.set_powerlimits((0,0))

cb.ax.minorticks_on()
cb.update_ticks()
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Thats great, many thanks! Interesting on the 'dark_background', I did not know about that. I'm using a black background in my plots here, however I wanted to be able to set any foreground/background color combination.